# iCarousel AutoLayout Multiplier issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, icarousel, layout-anchor

I am trying to use the multipliers on the iCarousel layout but they do not seem to have any affect at all. This is my code:

```
_carousel = [[iCarousel alloc]init ];
self.items = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    [_items addObject:@(i)];
}
_carousel.type = iCarouselTypeCylinder;

_carousel.delegate = self;
_carousel.dataSource = self;

_carousel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

[self.view addSubview:_carousel];

[_carousel.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.layoutMarginsGuide.centerXAnchor].active = true;
[_carousel.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor constant:-80].active = true;

[_carousel.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.widthAnchor multiplier:40.0/100.0].active = true;
[_carousel.heightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.heightAnchor multiplier:30.0/100.0].active = true;
```

I have also noticed that if a input a constant value of the  say -20 in:

```
[_carousel.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor constant:-20].active = true;
```

the iCarousel drops well below the views bottom anchor and I don't know why?

Can anyone answer these please, forgive me if I've overlooked anything as I'am new to programmatic layouts.

Answer (score 0):

You should override and move your code to `loadView` to avoid having the auto layout engine generate prototyping constraints. For example:

```
- (void) loadView
{
   [super loadView];

   _carousel = [[iCarousel alloc]init ];
    self.items = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        [_items addObject:@(i)];
    }
    _carousel.type = iCarouselTypeCylinder;

    _carousel.delegate = self;
    _carousel.dataSource = self;

     _carousel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

    [self.view addSubview:_carousel];

    [_carousel.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.layoutMarginsGuide.centerXAnchor].active = true;
    [_carousel.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor constant:-80].active = true;

    [_carousel.widthAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.widthAnchor multiplier:40.0/100.0].active = true;
    [_carousel.heightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.heightAnchor multiplier:30.0/100.0].active = true;  
}
```

In general `loadView` is where you want to add subviews programmatically to a `UIViewController` subclass.

Comment: Thank you for that :)  Can you help me with the question please?

Comment: Did you try this code? This fixed auto layout issues for me when running your code, as prototype constraints where causing auto layout constraints to break. Where is the code I've posted in your `UIViewController` or `UIView` lifecycle?

Comment: I am not using IB so there are no prototyping constraints. These blocks of code(constraintEqualToAnchor: multiplier  methods) work correctly elsewhere in the program but not on the iCarousel. I cannot place this code in 'loadView' because in my program the setup of the iCarousel happens after the view has loaded and based on a conditional. The iCarousel is positioned by the centerX and bottom anchors  but the multiplier's have no effect, resulting in the iCarousel being the same size in points on all devices, which I don't want. I want it to resize accordingly on different screen sizes

Comment: ok so this is weird... I have commented out every constraint assigned to the iCarousel and it is instead being given its size/position via 'initWithFrame' but I am getting 'Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints' warning?? There are no constraints assigned to it?

Comment: You have no storyboard or Xib files whatsoever? You can add the carousel in `loadView`, hide it, and remove it later if not needed. Auto layout generates constraints for you. If you set up your constraints before they are generated they won't be and will give you your expected result.

Comment: I have a xib file but I am doing all layout programmatically as per the requirements of the program. Why would constraints be auto generated for me in this case? I am really puzzled as to why the multiplier has no effect on the iCarousel. Would you know how I can apply the settings I'm trying to apply to the iCarousel in my case?

Comment: You should try `_carousel.clipsToBounds = YES`

Comment: I tried it but it just means a rectangular centre of the iCarousel is displayed and the rest of it is hidden

Comment: Right but is it in the right position and the right size? If so you should adjust the size of the items in the carousel to display nicely in those dimensions.

Comment: I made the items smaller to display in those dimensions but the multipliers still have no effect and the carousel doesn't size correctly/at all  in all devices :/ I appreciate your help. I even have this posted in the iCarousel GitHub issues but no responses...  very puzzling.

Comment: You should try posting screen shots of what you're getting and what you're expecting.